# Capture second part of the string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have a set of strings

The strings either start with `warning_with_` or start with `breakdown_with_`. I want to extract out `door_cycling`, the center portion

Or the text after `warning_with_` / `breakdown_with_`

And in case of no match the string is returned as is.

```
"warning_with_door_cycling_floor_n_door_b" --> regex should return  ---- door_cycling
"breakdown_with_door_cycling_door_:door:"  --> regex should return  ---- door_cycling
"breakdown_with_door_cycling_door_a"       --> regex should return  ----  door_cycling
"breakdown_with_bumps_at_location"         --> regex should return  ----  bumps_at_location
"unknown_string"                           --> regex should return  ----  unknown_string
```

So far this is what I have done

```
const regex = /(warning_with_|breakdown_with_)(\w+?)(?:(_floor_|_door_).+)/;

// But it does not work for this case
"breakdown_with_bumps_at_location".replace(regex, '$2');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is using an OR to separate two different matchers. The first matcher looks for the middle word, while the second one matches words where the "*floor*" or "*door*" suffix is missing.

The only other adjustment is to replace with the third grouping in the regular expression instead of the second grouping:

```
const data = [
  "warning_with_door_cycling_floor_n_door_b", 
  "breakdown_with_door_cycling_door_:door:", 
  "breakdown_with_door_cycling_door_a", 
  "breakdown_with_bumps_at_location", 
  "unknown_string"
];

const regex = /((warning_with_|breakdown_with_)(\w+?)(?:(_floor_|_door_).+))|((warning_with_|breakdown_with_))/;

data.forEach((elem) => console.log(elem.replace(regex, '$3')));
```

Comment: Hey Thanks It works. What if I now have to cater another string `elevator_started_door_open_floor_10_door_b` which should return `elevator_started_door_open` making the `warning_with` and `breakdown_with` the first part optional?

Comment: Try another OR at the beginning instead of the end.